# wifi usb dongle detected but no wlan interface

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb

I'm using ubuntu 12.04. When I insert my philips PTA01 usb wifi dongle, in dmesg i can see:

```
[ 1181.535290] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[ 1181.684074] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0471, idProduct=209e
[ 1181.684086] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
[ 1181.684093] usb 2-3: Product: PTA-01
[ 1181.684100] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: PHILIPS TV
[ 1181.684105] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 10
```

`dmesg | grep ath`:

```
[  367.861626] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
```

but still there is no wlan interface when I do *ifconfig*. Just *eth0* and *lo*. How can I turn wifi on?

in case it's relevant. `uname -a`:

```
Linux myhost 3.5.0-28-generic #48~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 24 21:42:24 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You may need the driver 'ath9k_htc' - see [here](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/Philips_PTA01) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2084360). The latter post seems to show that it is unsolved (firmware issue)...